# Remove space from URL using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

**I have this paragraph:**

The Daily Eastern News is a student-run newspaper published for the community of Eastern Illinois University in Charleston, Illinois. The newspaper was founded in 1915 ***http://media. www. dennews. com/media/storage/paper309/news/2005/11/04/News/TheNews. Turns.90-1045667. shtml*** and publishes on weekdays during the school year and twice-weekly in the summer.

The paper has won numerous state and national awards, including several Pacemaker awards. ***http://search. atomz. com/search/?sp_a=sp01089f00&sp_f=iso-8859-1&sp_q=%22daily+eastern+news%22*** The paper's editorial, production, and advertising staff are composed entirely of students from a range of degree programs.

I want to **remove the space** from the **bold parts** in above **paragraph**.

**Expected Output:**

The Daily Eastern News is a student-run newspaper published for the community of Eastern Illinois University in Charleston, Illinois. The newspaper was founded in 1915 ***http://media.www.dennews.com/media/storage/paper309/news/2005/11/04/News/TheNews.Turns.90-1045667.shtml*** and publishes on weekdays during the school year and twice-weekly in the summer.

The paper has won numerous state and national awards, including several Pacemaker awards. ***http://search. atomz. com/search/?sp_a=sp01089f00&sp_f=iso-8859-1&sp_q=%22daily+eastern+news%22*** The paper's editorial, production, and advertising staff are composed entirely of students from a range of degree programs.

Tried regexp - `(http://(?:.)*?\.) ((?:.)*?\.) ((?:.)*?\.) ((?:.)*?\.) ((?:.)*?\.)`

But it is working for the first URL **not** for the second URL. Because I used this `((?:.)*?\.)` to check repetitive group of .(dot) with space. It doesn't seems to be worked for second URL. Is there any way to do such thing for all URL.

Check this - https://regex101.com/r/tB9oL5/7

Comment: Do the paragraphs come with **bold** markup, like `<b>http://media.www ... .shtml</b>` or is it just plain text?

Comment: You can simply use `"(\.\s|\s\.)+"` pattern to get rid of any trailing or leading spaces. No, this is not what you want, but Yes - this is simpler than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible, unless you make assumptions such as require the URLs to appear at the end of sentences, end with `.html` etc. (and that is unreasonable, especially because all the links in your example *don't* appear at the end of sentence nor end with common suffix). To illustrate the reason why this is not possible, observe how you can't tell difference between:

> A new site: [http://example.com/](http://example.com) appeared.

and:

> A new site: [http://example.com/ appeared](http://example.com/appeared).

Answer (score 0):

possibly something like this?;

```
list = str.split('http://search. atomz. com/search/?sp_a=sp01089f00&sp_f=iso-8859-1&sp_q=%22daily+eastern+news%22')
nlist = ''.join(list)
print nlist
```

which returns; `http://search.atomz.com/search/?sp_a=sp01089f00&sp_f=iso-8859-1&sp_q=%22daily+eastern+news%22`

You may need to complicate it with variables etc, since this is a barebones function..